# Google Maps Polygon center not updating when dragged around

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am creating a map that allows the user to edit a polygon. When they click edit, the user drags the polygon it's supposed to get the new coordinates and by using js `LatLngBounds()` it should recalculate the new center so it can be saved in a DB as the new center of the map. My problem is that even though the coordinates of the polygon location are being updated as they should with every drag, the new center only updates with the first drag.

```
zoom = 14;
center = { lat: 42.517507245039106, lng: -113.71461353607174 }
zonedata = [{lat: 42.52174788319468, lng: -113.71611522387695},
    {lat: 42.51826478153626, lng: -113.72565284826658},
    {lat: 42.51326660688353, lng: -113.7043792873535},
    {lat: 42.520336574464594, lng: -113.70357422387696}]

var editmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: center,
    zoom: zoom
});
var editzones = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: zonedata,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    strokeWeight: 0,
    draggable: true,
    editable: true
});
editzones.setMap(editmap);
var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager();
drawingManager.setMap(editmap);
google.maps.event.addListener(editzones, 'dragend', function(){
    var polypath = editzones.getPath();
    coordinates = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0 ; i < polypath.length ; i++) {
        bounds.extend(zonedata[i]);
        coordinates.push({
        lat: polypath.getAt(i).lat(),
        lng: polypath.getAt(i).lng()
        });
    }
    var lat = bounds.getCenter().lat().toString();
    var lng = bounds.getCenter().lng().toString();
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    stringlocation = JSON.stringify(coordinates);
    stringcenter = JSON.stringify(center);
    console.log(stringcenter + stringlocation);
});
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code.  You are using the original data to extend the bounds, the original data won't change, you need to extend the bounds with the new values of the Polygon path:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(editzones, 'dragend', function(){
    var polypath = editzones.getPath();
    coordinates = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0 ; i < polypath.length ; i++) {
        bounds.extend(zonedata[i]); // <======= typo, this is the original array, it won't change.
        coordinates.push({
        lat: polypath.getAt(i).lat(),
        lng: polypath.getAt(i).lng()
        });
    }
    var lat = bounds.getCenter().lat().toString();
    var lng = bounds.getCenter().lng().toString();
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    stringlocation = JSON.stringify(coordinates);
    stringcenter = JSON.stringify(center);
    console.log(stringcenter + stringlocation);
});
```

should be:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(editzones, 'dragend', function(){
    var polypath = editzones.getPath();
    coordinates = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0 ; i < polypath.length ; i++) {
        bounds.extend(polypath.getAt(i)); // <==== updated path of polygon
        coordinates.push({
        lat: polypath.getAt(i).lat(),
        lng: polypath.getAt(i).lng()
        });
    }
    var lat = bounds.getCenter().lat().toString();
    var lng = bounds.getCenter().lng().toString();
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    stringlocation = JSON.stringify(coordinates);
    stringcenter = JSON.stringify(center);
    console.log(stringcenter + stringlocation);
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/yc1x65gm/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var zonedata = [{
    lat: 37.467776,
    lng: -122.155194
  },
  {
    lat: 37.448836,
    lng: -122.173734
  },
  {
    lat: 37.446928,
    lng: -122.121549
  }
]

function initialize() {
  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);
  var zoom = 13;
  var editmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: center,
    zoom: zoom
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(editmap, 'click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.latLng.toUrlValue(6));
  });
  var editzones = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: zonedata,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    strokeWeight: 0,
    draggable: true,
    editable: true
  });
  editzones.setMap(editmap);
  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager();
  drawingManager.setMap(editmap);
  google.maps.event.addListener(editzones, 'dragend', function() {
    var polypath = editzones.getPath();
    coordinates = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < polypath.length; i++) {
      bounds.extend(polypath.getAt(i));
      coordinates.push({
        lat: polypath.getAt(i).lat(),
        lng: polypath.getAt(i).lng()
      });
    }
    var center = bounds.getCenter();
    stringlocation = JSON.stringify(coordinates);
    stringcenter = JSON.stringify(center);
    console.log(stringcenter + stringlocation);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,drawing&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```